# Splitting curly braces imports to many lines in WebStorm autoformatting

Tags: webstorm

Is it possible to split curly braces import into many lines when more than one thing is imported?
I want something like this:

```
import {
  property1,
  property2,
  property3
} from './myModule.js'
```

instead of

```
import { property1, property2, property3 } from './myModule.js'
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. This automatically happens depending on your hard wrap settings.